# inkscape : fill a quadrilateral with four different colors

Tags: inkscape, color

I created a quadrilateral using the straight lines tool and another two dashed lines to have four quadrilaterals. I want to assign four different colors to each of them.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable advanced snapping options as follows

[image]

With the Bézier tool <kbd>B</kbd>, draw each colour piece as a closed shape, select a fill, no stroke, and send to the back <kbd>End</kbd>

[image]

Another method would be to construct in a similar way, but with simple squares instead, group them, and then apply a Perspective/Envelope  Live Path Effect, set to "Envelope deformation". Then move the control nodes using the Edit Paths by Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd>

[image]